# Configurar server local para angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, webservice, glassfish

como desarrollador siempre he subido mis proyectos a un cloud server, en los cuales solo sigues los pasos que te dan para subirlo, estos ya están adecuados.  Pero ahora debo subirlo a un server local situado en la empresa, el proyecto es un API Rest en java y el frontend hecho con Angularjs, base de datos MySQL, para el backend tengo entendido que solo es instalar el server ya sea glassfish, wildfly u otros, allí se sube el script de la bd, se crea el pool de conexión y se sube el .war que se genera y listo, todo esto se hace por el admin console que se abre con el navegador; pero ¿para AngularJS (Angular 1) que debo instalar en mi servidor de modo que lo soporte y que pueda consumir los servicios del backend?, y que no genere conflicto con lo demás... gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instala `Wampserver` [Aqui](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Después copia tu proyecto **frontend(AngularJS (Angular 1))** en la siguiente carpeta que creo la instalación `C:\wamp64\www`, y con esto es suficiente para que puedes consumir los servicios Rest, claro ya teniendo levantado tu servidor de aplicaciones por ejemplo `glassfish` y tu `.war` ya montado en el servidor.

Y a tu aplicación ingresarías de la siguiente manera `http://localhost:8081/nombreProyectoCarpeta`  el numero del puerto depende de cual le asignes al Wampserver para que levante.

Comment: Gracias estaba perdido con el server para el angular.  Pero tengo una duda, esto es para que lo puedan usar todos los de la empresa es una app de uso interno, ¿de esta forma todos podrían acceder desde cualquier maquina, apuntando a esa dirección?.

Comment: Si pueden ingresar pero no apuntando a localhost tendrías que sustituirlo por tu ip por ejemplo http://192.168.1.56:8081/nombreProyectoCarpeta, quiero pensar que en tu empresa tienen algún servidor en donde lo puedas montar, así en lugar de tu ip iría la de ese servidor o el nombre de dominio que tenga asignado.

Comment: excelente solución saludos.